# Open modal at the click of a button in a gridview Yii2

Tags: ajax, gridview, controller, yii2, action

I need this button in grid open a modal , but is not working

this is the column:

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{getRespostaPossivel}',
            'buttons' => [
            'getRespostaPossivel' => function ($url, $model) {
                    if($model->classeResposta->indr_resposta_possivel){
                        return Html::buttonInput('Respostas Possíveis',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs','id' => 'modal-open','onclick' => 
                            "$('#modal').modal('show');
                            $.ajax({
                                url : 'getFormRespostaPossivel',
                                data : {'id' : $model->id},
                                success  : function(data) {
                                    $('.modal-body').html(data);
                                }
                            });
                        "]);
                    }
                },
            ],
        ],
```

and action:

```
public function actionGetFormRespostaPossivel($id)
    {
        $searchModel = new RespostaPossivelUsuarioSearch();
        $searchModel->tblcaus_id = $id;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('_form', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ],true,true);
    }
```

someone could help me with this problem ?

Comment: please describe the expected behaviour and error messages if any

Comment: blank modal open after clicking button ?

Comment: Check javascript console for errors. When you pass the url to your ajax call, are you sure `getFormRespostaPossivel` has a meaningful value?